# Count with MongoDB aggregate $group result

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a database query with **pymongo** , like so

```
pipeline = [
    {"$group": {"_id": "$product", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
]
rows = list(collection_name.aggregate(pipeline))
print(rows)
```

The result like to

```
[
    {'_id': 'p1', 'count': 45},
    {'_id': 'p2', 'count': 4},
    {'_id': 'p3', 'count': 96},
    {'_id': 'p1', 'count': 23},
    {'_id': 'p4', 'count': 10}
]
```

**Objective**:

On the basis of the above results, I want to conduct statistics between partitions. For example, To get the number of count times in the following intervals:

```
partition, count
(0, 10], 2
[11, 50), 2
[50, 100], 1
```

Is there a way of doing this entirely using MongoDB aggregate framework?

Any comments would be very helpful. Thanks.

---

**Answer** by @Wernfried Domscheit

#### `$bucket`

```
pipeline = [
    {"$group": {"_id": "$product", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
    {"$bucket": {
        "groupBy": "$count",
        "boundaries": [0, 11, 51, 100],
        "default": "Other",
        "output": {
            "count": {"$sum": 1},
        }
    }}
]
rows = list(tbl_athletes.aggregate(pipeline))
rows
```

#### `$bucketAuto`

```
pipeline = [
    {"$group": {"_id": "$product", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
    {"$bucketAuto": {
        "groupBy": "$count",
        "buckets": 5,
        "output": {
            "count": {"$sum": 1},
        }
    }}
]
rows = list(tbl_athletes.aggregate(pipeline))
rows
```

NOTICE:

**In `$bucket`，`default` must be there.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have the [$bucket](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) operator for that:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $bucket: {
         groupBy: "$count",
         boundaries: [0, 11, 51, 100],
         output: {
            count: { $sum: 1 },
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Or use [$bucketAuto](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucketAuto/#granularity) where the intervals are generated automatically.

Comment: Save my day! Thanks so much!